# Windows Server: What software is available to report directory size?

Tags: windows, disk-space-utilization

I can not run File Server Resource Manager due to the fact that we have VSS disabled.

What other software is available that will report the size of directories recursively, automatically and send an email?

I began coding a program, but I'm hoping to find an existing piece of software that performs the desired task; since calculating "all contained below X" seems overly complex.

[edit]
here is a program I found with a CLI interface, but it isn't free: http://www.xinorbis.com/xinorbiscom/index.htm

Comment: shameless self-plug: [quick batch script to gather size report in a file](http://mbrownnyc.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/quick-batch-to-report-directory-size/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set something up with [Disk Usage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651) from [Windows Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default)

Comment: There's also a win32 port of the gnu core utils where du is included: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Answer (score 3):

http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/online_manual/EN/index.html?command_line_opt.html

http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/screens.shtml

You can use treesize to view recursive disk report and further use it's commandline options, then compile a command and it will also allow you to get a report in email.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks.  I was using this until the demo ran out actually!  Do you know of an open source/free replacement?  edit: I think I answered my own questions http://alternativeto.net/software/treesize-free/?license=opensource

Comment: I'm a big fan of windirstat.

Comment: I use SpaceSniffer when I need a quick shot.  I am mostly concerned with running scheduled reports, which I don't think you can do in windirstat?

Answer (score 3):

http://windirstat.info/ is great.

even has pretty colors!

Answer (score 0):

[PA Storage Monitor](http://www.poweradmin.com/storage-monitor) will show you directory sizes, across time, and email you a report if you want.